# What are the use cases for AtomicFile?

Tags: android, kotlin, atomic, android-file

I'm having trouble understanding the use cases for [AtomicFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AtomicFile). Since it does not confer any thread safety, is it just for ensuring no partial/invalid files are written if the app crashes or device loses power during a file write? What would be the purpose of reading a file with AtomicFile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it just for ensuring no partial/invalid files are written if the app crashes or device loses power during a file write?

Yes.

Adding on to the cases, the OS can kill the process at anytime. `AtomicFile` should provide atomic guarantees in that case too.

Comment: Any idea why I'd want to read the file atomically?

Comment: I guess, if a file is locked it need to wait untill its unlocked,then start read.

Comment: @MohamedRimshad `AtomicFile` does not use file locking. Reading a file "atomically" means that you won't read a partially written/updated file.

Comment: @SteveM see the comment above

Comment: @SteveM To be more accurate, in this context there is no such thing as "atomic reading". All you do is "read". `AtomicFile` provides atomic writing and therefore the reads will never see partially written files. An important note is that you can't mix reading with `AtomicFile` and writing with `File` because `AtomicFile` uses 2 files in order to provide atomicity: the actual file and the temporary the file. `AtomicFile` reads the *actual* file and writes to a *temporary* file. Only when you call `finishWrite()` does `AtomicFile` atomically rename the `temporary` file to the `actual` file.